# Concatenate Multiple TEXT and Variables into one string iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, xcode5

I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with what I believe is simple concatenation, and I must be missing something here - see code below:

```
NSString *combinedValues = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                            @"I am at %@" self.dancePlace.text
                            @" Airport, and I will arrive on %@" danceDateValue,
                            @" from %@" timeIn,
                            @" to %@" timeOut,
                            @" at Terminal %@" self.danceTerminal.text
                            @" Gate %@" self.danceGate.text];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is a good way

```
NSString *combinedValues = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                            @"I am at %@ Airport, and I will arrive on %@ from %@ to %@ at Terminal %@ Gate %@" , self.dancePlace.text, danceDateValue, timeIn, timeOut, self.danceTerminal.text, self.danceGate.text];
```

Comment: it wouldn't let me until 10 minutes had passed.  :-)